# finding a point in a polygon

Tags: polygon, triangulation

Imagine a cellphone tower (red) and static cell phones (green) where the cellphone locations are known and FIXED. (ie, I know the x,y coordinate as well as the DISTANCE to each cell tower from a green location.)

Given the above I want find the x,y coordinate of an unknown device (orange) on the plane? The orange device can only give its distance to anyone of the cell towers but it knows nothing about the static devices (green).

Is there a way of finding the x,y of the orange device? [image]

Comment: Do you know the positions and orientations of the towers? Or do you need to work that out first from the static phones?

Comment: Lets assume the location of the towers is known.

Comment: Do you know how to find the intersection of two circles, given their centers and radii?

Comment: Seems like the cell phones are unimportant, the three towers are enough to perform the trilateration (not triangulation).

Comment: my original thought was to use the cell phone's static position to estimate the location. because I know the distance of each fixed point to the tower, I can guestimate the position of the device. But I am not sure if there's a better algorithm given the use of the fixed points.

Comment: You're simply doing the same thing twice: using the distances from the located cell phones to locate the towers, then using the distances from the located towers to locate the device. It's not a difficult problem, but it's not clear which part is giving you trouble. *Do you know how to find the intersection of two circles?*

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this looks like a homework assignment. Also, AFAICS, this has nothing to do with finding a point in a polygon.

Nevertheless ...

1. since you know the distance of each green device from each cell tower, these distances are effectively the radii of circles so find the intersection of circles. (Two devices will render two solutions, so use the third device and circle intersections again to determine which of the first two solutions was the correct one.)
2. repeat step one above for each cell tower.
3. Then for each orange device repeat the same process - ie finding intersections of circles using distances from three towers.